# py2exe and Django Import Error no module named apps

Tags: python, django, py2exe

I'm trying to make a standalone Django (1.8.2) app using py2exe.

To achieve that I have a setup.py file with all settings required by py2exe: modules to be included, not to include, etc. The py2exe console parameter (within my setup.py) is set to 'manage.py'. After running it with `python setup.py py2exe` py2exe runs succesfully adding all (?) required modules and my Django apps. I get an manage.exe file - seems this is working, right?

However, after running the manage.exe file I get the following error:

```
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
File "django\core\management\__init__.pyo", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
File "django\core\management\__init__.pyo", line 312, in execute
File "django\__init__.pyo", line 18, in setup
File "django\apps\registry.pyo", line 85, in populate
File "django\apps\config.pyo", line 112, in create
File "importlib\__init__.pyo", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named apps
```

I have added `django.apps` to the setup.py import modules part and it didn't solve the problem. Why is this happening and how to fix that?

UPDATE:

For the setup.py file I have followed this website: https://misunderstandings.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/django-desktop-app/ and after customizing it to my needs here's what I have ended-up with:

setup.py:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
import reportlab

def add_path_tree( base_path, path, skip_dirs=[ '.svn', '.git' ]):
  path = os.path.join( base_path, path )
  partial_data_files = []
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk( os.path.join( path )):
    sample_list = []
    for skip_dir in skip_dirs:
      if skip_dir in dirs:
        dirs.remove( skip_dir )
    if files:
      for filename in files:
        sample_list.append( os.path.join( root, filename ))
    if sample_list:
      partial_data_files.append((
        root.replace(
          base_path + os.sep if base_path else '',
          '',
          1
        ),
        sample_list
      ))
  return partial_data_files


 py2exe_options = {
    'py2exe': {
      'compressed': 1,
      'optimize': 2,
      'ascii': 1,
      'bundle_files': 1,
      'dist_dir': 'dist',
      'packages': [ 'encodings','gabinet','pacjent','kalendarz','terapeuta','superwizja','ustawienia','zapiszsesje_registration', ],
      'excludes' : [
        'pywin',
        'pywin.debugger',
        'pywin.debugger.dbgcon',
        'pywin.dialogs',
        'pywin.dialogs.list',
        'Tkconstants',
        'Tkinter',
        'tcl',
      ],
      'dll_excludes': [ 'w9xpopen.exe', 'MSVCR71.dll' ],
      'includes': [
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories',
        'django.middleware.common',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.core.cache.backends',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.base',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.introspection',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.creation',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.client',
        'django.template.defaulttags',
        'django.template.defaultfilters',
        'django.template.loader_tags',
        'django.contrib.admin.views.main',
        'django.core.context_processors',
        'django.contrib.auth.views',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends',
        'django.views.static',
        'django.views.defaults',
        'django.core.cache.backends.locmem',
        'django.templatetags.i18n',
        'django.views.i18n',
        'django.apps',
        'email.mime.audio',
        'email.mime.base',
        'email.mime.image',
        'email.mime.message',
        'email.mime.multipart',
        'email.mime.nonmultipart',
        'email.mime.text',
        'email.charset',
        'email.encoders',
        'email.errors',
        'email.feedparser',
        'email.generator',
        'email.header',
        'email.iterators',
        'email.message',
        'email.parser',
        'email.utils',
        'email.base64mime',
        'email.quoprimime',
            'django.db.backends.sqlite3.base',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.introspection',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.creation',
        'django.db.backends.sqlite3.client',
        'django.apps', 
        'django.template.defaulttags',
        'django.template.defaultfilters',
        'django.template.loader_tags',
        'django.core.wsgi',
        'gabinet.forms',
        'gabinet.models',
        'gabinet.urls',
        'gabinet.views',
        'kalendarz.forms',
        'kalendarz.models',
        'kalendarz.urls',
        'kalendarz.views',
        'pacjent.forms',
        'pacjent.models',
        'pacjent.urls',
        'pacjent.views',
        'superwizja.models',
        'superwizja.urls',
        'superwizja.urls',
        'superwizja.views',
        'terapeuta.models',
        'terapeuta.settings',
        'terapeuta.urls',
        'terapeuta.views',
        'terapeuta.wsgi',
        'ustawienia.forms',
        'ustawienia.models',
        'ustawienia.urls',
        'ustawienia.views',
        'zapiszsesje_registration.auth_urls',
        'zapiszsesje_registration.forms',
        'zapiszsesje_registration.models',
        'zapiszsesje_registration.urls',
        'zapiszsesje_registration.views',
      ],
    }
  }

  # Take the first value from the environment variable PYTHON_PATH
  python_path = os.environ[ 'PYTHONPATH' ].split( ';' )[ 0 ]

  django_admin_path = os.path.normpath( python_path + '/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin' )
  py2exe_data_files = []

  # django admin files
  py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( django_admin_path, 'templates' )
  py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( django_admin_path, 'media' )
  # project files
  py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( '', 'db' )
  py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( '', 'templates' )

  setup(
    options=py2exe_options,
    data_files=py2exe_data_files,
    zipfile = None,
    console=[ 'manage.py' ],
  )
```

Comment: Please post the `py2exe` script

Comment: I've updated the question with the setup.py code - please see above - thx!

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: No - I've used PyInstaller instead and that worked! :)