# Portable python package with Django inside?

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv, portability

So, I'm trying to figure out, how to create fully portable python package having my venv included with django and several other related packages.

I know this question is not new, but all tools are exists for freezing python apps on windows are not doing what I need. p2exe, pyInstaller, etc, are good but can't handle django framework.

I want my app has one exe, which will start

1. python intpreter from subfolder
2. my venv with django and other deps
3. manage.py runserver with params

Currently 2 and 3 works, if user installed python before runing my starter script *(I'm actually wrapping all this with electron, so my web-app will be usable separately from browser)*

The main question is how to adjust/modify python to work with provided venv, without having it installed on target machine?

Comment: Python virtualenvs **are not portable** and you probably know that because of "*I know this question is not new*". Please stop trying and look for a different solution. Like `py2exe` + InnoSetup or NSIS Installer. I had been using `py2exe` + InnoSetup for more than 10 years.

Comment: Sorry, but I coldn't find any way how to package django web app with py2exe. This is why I asking this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+py2exe. People [report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735536/py2exe-and-django-import-error-no-module-named-apps#comment56294439_32735536) that PyInstaller works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/). When used properly you should be able to run your project on any machine in exactly the same way that you are currently running it locally.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) is a tutorial specifically for Django projects.

Comment: Hm... I read about docker and it's possibilities, so it seems to have required functionality, but it actually broken all my VMs during install (I need them on my work), so I have to remove it and rollback some system features before trying package my project in question. 

Is it possible to use docker desktop inside other Windows VM? 
Do my final user have to install docker to run my container?